# How to remove rows that contain duplicate characters in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, duplicates

I want remove entire row if there are duplicates in two columns. Any quick help in doing so in R (for very large dataset) would be highly appreciated. For example:

```
mydf <- data.frame(p1=c('a','a','a','b','g','b','c','c','d'),
                               p2=c('b','c','d','c','d','e','d','e','e'),
                               value=c(10,20,10,11,12,13,14,15,16))
```

This gives:

```
mydf

 p1 p2 value
1  a  b    10
2  c  c    20
3  a  d    10
4  b  c    11
5  d  d    12
6  b  b    13
7  c  d    14
8  c  e    15
9  e  e    16
```

I want to get:

```
p1 p2 value
1  a  b    10
2  a  d    10
3  b  c    11
4  c  d    14
5  c  e    15
```

Comment: `subset(mydf, p1 != p2)`

Comment: Worked. Just addition question. if  "New York" and "New.York" present in two columns of same row, the code won't remove. Do you have suggestion for such situation?

Comment: @Discovery2020 - provided a framework for you to address this issue below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your note in the comments suggests your actual problem is more complex. There's some preprocessing you could do to your strings before you compare `p1` to `p2`. You will have the domain expertise to know what steps are appropriate, but here's a first start. I remove all spaced and punctuation from `p1` and `p2`. I then convert them all to uppercase before testing for equality. You can modify the `clean_str` function to include more / different cleaning operations.

Additionally, you may consider approximate matching to address typos / colloquial naming conventions. Package [stringdist](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringdist/versions/0.9.5.5/topics/stringdist) is a good place to start.

```r
mydf <- data.frame(p1=c('New York','New York','New York','TokYo','LosAngeles','MEMPHIS','memphis','ChIcAGo','Cleveland'),
                   p2=c('new York','New.York','MEMPHIS','Chicago','knoxville','tokyo','LosAngeles','Chicago','CLEVELAND'),
                   value=c(10,20,10,11,12,13,14,15,16),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


mydf[mydf$p1 != mydf$p2,]
#>           p1         p2 value
#> 1   New York   new York    10
#> 2   New York   New.York    20
#> 3   New York    MEMPHIS    10
#> 4      TokYo    Chicago    11
#> 5 LosAngeles  knoxville    12
#> 6    MEMPHIS      tokyo    13
#> 7    memphis LosAngeles    14
#> 8    ChIcAGo    Chicago    15
#> 9  Cleveland  CLEVELAND    16

clean_str <- function(col){
  #removes all punctuation
  d <- gsub("[[:punct:][:blank:]]+", "", col)
  d <- toupper(d)
  return(d)
}

mydf$p1 <- clean_str(mydf$p1)
mydf$p2 <- clean_str(mydf$p2)

mydf[mydf$p1 != mydf$p2,]
#>           p1         p2 value
#> 3    NEWYORK    MEMPHIS    10
#> 4      TOKYO    CHICAGO    11
#> 5 LOSANGELES  KNOXVILLE    12
#> 6    MEMPHIS      TOKYO    13
#> 7    MEMPHIS LOSANGELES    14
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I have pretty large data (14 k rows and 1k columns). I would like to eliminate the problem when copying data  from csv file. This would be easier and efficient.

Comment: @Discovery2020 - based on the general outline above, I don't think you can do this 'when copying data from CSV file. They are different steps, but should be reasonably performance based on your file size. You could write a function that looked something like `read_and_process <- function(file){ #1) read CSV; #2 process CSV)`. You could pretty easily `apply()` the processing function across all relevant columns.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways to do that. Among them :

## Base R

```r
mydf[mydf$p1 != mydf$p2, ]
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% filter(p1 != p2)
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)
mydf[p1 != p2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a two-step solution based on @Chase's data:

First step (as suggested by @Chase) - preprocess your data in `p1`and `p2`to make them comparable:

```
# set to lower-case:
mydf[,c("p1", "p2")] <- lapply(mydf[,c("p1", "p2")], tolower)
# remove anything that's not alphanumeric between words:
mydf[,c("p1", "p2")] <- lapply(mydf[,c("p1", "p2")], function(x) gsub("(\\w+)\\W(\\w+)", "\\1\\2", x))
```

Second step - (i) using `apply`, `paste` the rows together, (ii) use `grepl` and backreference `\\1` to look out for immediately adjacent duplicates in these rows, and (iii) remove (`-`) those rows `which` contain these duplicates:

```
mydf[-which(grepl("\\b(\\w+)\\s+\\1\\b", apply(mydf, 1, paste0, collapse = " "))),]
          p1         p2 value
3    newyork    memphis    10
4      tokyo    chicago    11
5 losangeles  knoxville    12
6    memphis      tokyo    13
7    memphis losangeles    14
```

Comment: I have pretty large data (14 k rows and 1k columns). I would like to eliminate the problem when copying data  from csv file. This would be easier and efficient.

Comment: You mean upon read-in? I don't know that that's possible. I don't see why you should not read-in the data first and process it then.